# inline if else throwing implicit conversion error, but regular else is working

Tags: c#, .net

So I'm trying to set a byte based on a boolean value I'm receiving from a view. I want to do it inline so it looks neater but for some reason it throws an "Cannot implicitly convert type int to byte" but when I try it with the traditional if else statement, it is working fine.

Can someone explain to me why this is happening?

```
        byte byteFlag1;

        byteFlag1 = boolFlag ? 1 : 0;
        // this throws an error


        byte byteFlag2;
        if( boolFlag )
        {
            byteFlag2= 1;
        } else
        {
            byteFlag2= 0;
        }
         // this works fine?
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no implicit conversion from an `integer` to a `byte`.  This is necessary as not all integers have a valid `byte` that they can be converted to.

There *is* a conversion from every numeric literal to any numeric type for which it is a valid value.  This conversion will always be valid *by definition*, if it wasn't, you'd have a *compile time* error indicating as much.

Comment: why is one considered an integer and one is considered a numeric literal in the above context?

Comment: I'm guessing the interesting part is why the complier can't figure out this when using the conditional operator

Comment: @JoeViscardi One is a numeric literal because...it's a number, and that's a numeric literal (by definition).  One isn't, because you performed an operation on it that wasn't resolved at compile time, making it no longer a literal.

Comment: @user6144226 So in the first example what value is going to be assigned to `byteFlag1`?  Will it be a 1 or a 2?

Comment: What is the operation being performed?

Comment: @JoeViscardi A conditional operation.

Comment: Is there a better way to do this without having to just implicitly pick which columns besides the one timestamp? I need to do this with over 100 tables and the code is all like how it was originally

Comment: @JoeViscardi You can use byte literals rather than integer literals, in the conditional operator, which means that no conversion from int to byte is ever needed.